# Unsure why this particular test case does not work for merging binary trees

Tags: java, recursion, tree, binary-tree, treenode

CS Student here practicing on leetcode.

I've been given the following problem:

[image]

No idea if this code is any good or not, would appreciate some feedback there as well, but here is what I worked out:

```
class Solution {
public TreeNode mergeTrees(TreeNode root1, TreeNode root2) {
    TreeNode ret = traverse(root1, root2);
    
    return ret;
    
    
}


public TreeNode traverse(TreeNode node1, TreeNode node2){
    TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode();
    
    if(node1 == null && node2 == null){
        return null;
    }
    else if(node1 == null){
        newNode.val = node2.val;
    }
    else if(node2 == null){
        newNode.val = node1.val;
    }
    else{
        newNode.val = node1.val + node2.val;
        newNode.left = traverse(node1.left, node2.left);
        newNode.right = traverse(node1.right, node2.right);
        
        
    }
    
    return newNode;
}
```

}

Seems to work ok with the sample input given in the example. When I submit the problem, however, I am given this case:

[image]

I arrive at the expected answer when I worked it out on paper based on the code I wrote. I am not sure why in this case my code is producing an erroneous result. Help me out here

EDIT: Changed phrasing for clarity

Comment: @kcsquared sorry! will edit

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are returning value only when both the nodes are null and not for other case where either node is null. Your code is not going to else statement for "either null" case and it gets returned to the calling function.

Changed code below:

```
  if(node1 == null && node2 == null){
    return null;
}
else if(node1 == null){
    newNode.val = node2.val;
    return node2;
}
else if(node2 == null){
    newNode.val = node1.val;
    return node1;
}
else{
    newNode.val = node1.val + node2.val;
    newNode.left = traverse(node1.left, node2.left);
    newNode.right = traverse(node1.right, node2.right);
}
```

Because newNode does not play a role, you can discard and merge directly into roo1 node.

```
public TreeNode mergeTrees(TreeNode root1, TreeNode root2) {
        if(root1 == null && root2 == null) {
            return null;
        } else if(root1 == null) {
            return root2;
        } else if (root2 == null) {
            return root1;
        } else {
            root1.val = root1.val + root2.val;
            root1.left = mergeTrees(root1.left, root2.left);
            root1.right = mergeTrees(root1.right, root2.right);
        }
        return root1;
```

This should work for you.

Comment: I can't say I understand. In any of the elseif/else cases, newNode is updated and it returns, then, newNode. Unless both node1 and node2 are null, it should return newNode with the appropriate subtree, unless I am missing something.

Comment: Your code runs correctly for 2 cases 
1. when both your nodes are null
2. when both your nodes are not null
Your code does not work for either side null because you are not returning instead your are exiting.

Comment: In either null case, always your newNode root is getting returned which is 2 in this usecase.